# F# FSI - Is there a limit to the script length? String Literal appears too long

Tags: f#, literals, fsi

On transferring a F# file  -- Jira.fs to a script file -- Jira.fsx

I am encountering a problem with a constant string that uses triple quotes and within it  contains double quotes (example below)

Jira.fs = success
Jira.fsx = fails with error FS0010: Unexpected symbol ':' in expression. Expected '}' or other token.

Warnings include - Warning: line too long, ignoring some characters

Is there a limit to .fsx scripts?

If so is there a recommended way around this? Just read in the string from a file?

Code below: thanks

```
[<Literal>]
let childIssueSchema = """ {"expand":"renderedFields,names,schema,transitions,operations,editmeta,changelog","id":"18043","self":"https://atlassian.au.MyCompany.net/jira/rest/api/latest/issue/18043","key":"DPMITPRODU-141","fields":{"progress":{"progress":0,"total":0},"summary":"APC - Calculator link on AOL ","customfield_10560":{"self":"https://atlassian.au.MyCompany.net/jira/rest/api/2/customFieldOption/10340","value":"Yes","id":"10340"},"customfield_11067":null,"timetracking":{},"customfield_11066":null,"issuetype":{"self":"https://atlassian.au.MyCompany.net/jira/rest/api/2/issuetype/6","id":"6","description":"A user story","iconUrl":"https://atlassian.au.MyCompany.net/jira/images/icons/sales.gif","name":"User Story","subtask":false},"customfield_10562":null,"customfield_11069":null,"customfield_11068":null,"customfield_11160":"4837","customfield_11161":null,"customfield_11660":null,"timespent":null,"reporter":{"self":"https://atlassian.au.MyCompany.net/jira/rest/api/2/user?username=lkaligotla","name":"lkaligotla","emailAddress":"lkaligotla@MyCompany.com.au","avatarUrls":{"16x16":"https://atlassian.au.MyCompany.net/jira/secure/useravatar?size=small&avatarId=10102","48x48":"https://atlassian.au.MyCompany.net/jira/secure/useravatar?avatarId=10102"},"displayName":"Lakshmi Kaligotla","active":true},"created":"2013-12-31T14:39:09.457+1100","updated":"2014-01-02T09:32:57.023+1100","customfield_10041":null,"priority":{"self":"https://atlassian.au.MyCompany.net/jira/rest/api/2/priority/3","iconUrl":"https://atlassian.au.MyCompany.net/jira/images/icons/priority_major.gif","name":"Medium","id":"3"},"description":"The current Age pension Calculator Icon must lead to a landing page with content and Start Calculator Button \r\n\r\nOn Click of start Calculator button calculator Home Page with instructions and start calculator button ","customfield_10002":null,"customfield_10003":null,"customfield_10040":null,"issuelinks":[{"id":"13177","self":"https://atlassian.au.MyCompany.net/jira/rest/api/2/issueLink/13177","type":{"id":"10010","name":"CrossProjectLink","inward":"part of","outward":"contains","self":"https://atlassian.au.MyCompany.net/jira/rest/api/2/issueLinkType/10010"},"inwardIssue":{"id":"18036","key":"DPMITPROJ-35","self":"https://atlassian.au.MyCompany.net/jira/rest/api/2/issue/18036","fields":{"summary":"APC - Calculator","status":{"self":"https://atlassian.au.MyCompany.net/jira/rest/api/2/status/10003","description":"User has placed this item in the queue","iconUrl":"https://atlassian.au.MyCompany.net/jira/images/icons/status_visible.gif","name":"In Queue","id":"10003"},"priority":{"self":"https://atlassian.au.MyCompany.net/jira/rest/api/2/priority/3","iconUrl":"https://atlassian.au.MyCompany.net/jira/images/icons/priority_major.gif","name":"Medium","id":"3"},"issuetype":{"self":"https://atlassian.au.MyCompany.net/jira/rest/api/2/issuetype/5","id":"5","description":"A big user story that needs to be broken down.","iconUrl":"https://atlassian.au.MyCompany.net/jira/download/resources/com.pyxis.greenhopper.jira:greenhopper-webactions/images/ico_epic.png","name":"Epic","subtask":false}}}}],"customfield_10000":null,"customfield_10765":null,"subtasks":[],"customfield_10767":null,"status":{"self":"https://atlassian.au.MyCompany.net/jira/rest/api/2/status/10016","description":"","iconUrl":"https://atlassian.au.MyCompany.net/jira/images/icons/status_open.gif","name":"Backlog","id":"10016"},"labels":[],"workratio":-1,"project":{"self":"https://atlassian.au.MyCompany.net/jira/rest/api/2/project/DPMITPRODU","id":"11433","key":"DPMITPRODU","name":"DPMIT-Products","avatarUrls":{"16x16":"https://atlassian.au.MyCompany.net/jira/secure/projectavatar?size=small&pid=11433&avatarId=11680","48x48":"https://atlassian.au.MyCompany.net/jira/secure/projectavatar?pid=11433&avatarId=11680"}},"environment":null,"customfield_10053":{"self":"https://atlassian.au.MyCompany.net/jira/rest/api/2/customFieldOption/10030","value":"Yes","id":"10030"},"aggregateprogress":{"progress":0,"total":0},"customfield_10050":"A link is available and on click leads to Calculor Landing page\r\nhttps://adviseronlineportal.com.au/Agepensioncalculator","components":[],"comment":{"startAt":0,"maxResults":0,"total":0,"comments":[]},"timeoriginalestimate":null,"customfield_10461":null,"customfield_10460":null,"customfield_11963":[{"self":"https://atlassian.au.MyCompany.net/jira/rest/api/2/customFieldOption/11441","value":"False","id":"11441"}],"customfield_10360":null,"votes":{"self":"https://atlassian.au.MyCompany.net/jira/rest/api/2/issue/DPMITPRODU-141/votes","votes":0,"hasVoted":false},"customfield_10261":null,"customfield_10262":null,"customfield_10263":{"self":"https://atlassian.au.MyCompany.net/jira/rest/api/2/customFieldOption/10061","value":"Yes","id":"10061"},"fixVersions":[],"resolution":null,"resolutiondate":null,"aggregatetimeoriginalestimate":null,"customfield_10161":null,"customfield_10160":null,"duedate":null,"customfield_10020":null,"customfield_10060":"4793","watches":{"self":"https://atlassian.au.MyCompany.net/jira/rest/api/2/issue/DPMITPRODU-141/watchers","watchCount":1,"isWatching":false},"customfield_10162":null,"worklog":{"startAt":0,"maxResults":0,"total":0,"worklogs":[]},"assignee":null,"attachment":[],"aggregatetimeestimate":null,"versions":[],"timeestimate":null,"customfield_10030":null,"customfield_10031":null,"aggregatetimespent":null}}  """

type ChildJsonSchema = FSharp.Data.JsonProvider< childIssueSchema >
```

Comment: You could always just put a line break - it seems like there is a maximum line length.  The relevant part of the code is https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/85e21e127ea5618cd2dad3515fec46c0bb251a27/src/fsharp/fsi/fsi.fs at line 1568

Comment: Thanks - the type provider wants a constant string so I guess Ill need to manually break up the large string

Comment: Just ran into this too and posted an issue: https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/issues/10765

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there is a limit on the size of a script file (not sure what would happen around 2GB, but that does not sound like a realistic scenario), but for some reason (not sure why!) there is a limit on a single line length.

This is a bit unfortunate when you just want to copy & paste sample for a JSON type provider, but if you're using `"""` quotes, then you can just have a newline character in the string and it will still be treated as a single constant string:

```
[<Literal>]
let childIssueSchema = """{"foo":1,
    "bar":42}"""
type ChildJsonSchema = FSharp.Data.JsonProvider<childIssueSchema>
```

That said, in case you have long and complex samples, it might be better to save them to files and just point the type provider to a file. Assuming you have `childIssue.json` in the same folder as the source file, you should be able to write:

```
type ChildJsonSchema = FSharp.Data.JsonProvider<"childIssue.json">
```